# GROUP BY failure in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have added a new statement in my query. I would like to calculate unit price too but i am taking " ORA-00904: "TOTAL_COST": invalid identifier ERROR"  Why?
How can I make this ?
Thanks in advance

````
Sum (A.Cost_Labor)+Sum (A.Cost_Material)+Sum ( A.Machine_Hours*C.Rate_Per_Hour) As Total_Cost,
    Total_Cost/A.Quantity_Produced as unit_price
´´´

Here is my whole query:

    ```

Select A.Job_Id, A.Location_Id,  B.Location_Name,
Substr(D.Contract_Date,0,4) As Year_Contract_Date,
    Substr(D.Contract_Date,5,2) As Month_Contract_Date,
    Sum (A.COST_LABOR)As Sum_COST_LABOR, 
    Sum (A.Cost_Material) As Sum_Material_Cost, 
    Sum ( A.Cost_Overhead) As Sum_Cost_Overhead,
    Sum ( A.Machine_Hours*C.Rate_Per_Hour) As Sum_Machine_Cost,  
    Sum(A.Quantity_Produced) As Sum_Quant_Prod,
    Sum (A.Cost_Labor)+Sum (A.Cost_Material)+Sum ( A.Machine_Hours*C.Rate_Per_Hour) As Total_Cost,
    Total_Cost/A.Quantity_Produced as unit_price
   
      From W_Sub_Job_F A, W_Location_D B, W_Machine_Type_D C, W_Job_F D, W_Time_D E
        Where A.Job_Id=D.Job_Id
        And A.Location_Id=B.Location_Id
        And A.Machine_Type_Id=C.Machine_Type_Id
        And D.Contract_Date=E.Time_Id
        Group By A.Job_Id, A.Location_Id, B.Location_Name, D.Contract_Date
        order by A.Job_Id, A.Location_Id, Year_Contract_Date,Month_Contract_Date ;
        ´´´
````

Comment: You can't SUM() a SUM().

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clauses.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.  You should also use meaningful table tables rather than arbitrary letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use TOTAL_COST in that way, it is a pseudo_column. You might use a subselect instead

```
select 
job_id ,
location_id ,
Location_Name ,
Year_Contract_Date,
Month_Contract_Date,
Sum_COST_LABOR,
Sum_Material_Cost,
Sum_Cost_Overhead ,
Sum_Machine_Cost ,
Sum_Quant_Prod ,
Total_Cost ,
Total_Cost/Sum_Quant_Prod as unit_price 
from 
(
Select A.Job_Id, A.Location_Id,  B.Location_Name,
Substr(D.Contract_Date,0,4) As Year_Contract_Date,
    Substr(D.Contract_Date,5,2) As Month_Contract_Date,
    Sum (A.COST_LABOR)As Sum_COST_LABOR, 
    Sum (A.Cost_Material) As Sum_Material_Cost, 
    Sum ( A.Cost_Overhead) As Sum_Cost_Overhead,
    Sum ( A.Machine_Hours*C.Rate_Per_Hour) As Sum_Machine_Cost,  
    Sum(A.Quantity_Produced) As Sum_Quant_Prod,
    Sum (A.Cost_Labor)+Sum (A.Cost_Material)+Sum ( A.Machine_Hours*C.Rate_Per_Hour) As Total_Cost  
      From W_Sub_Job_F A, W_Location_D B, W_Machine_Type_D C, W_Job_F D, W_Time_D E
        Where A.Job_Id=D.Job_Id
        And A.Location_Id=B.Location_Id
        And A.Machine_Type_Id=C.Machine_Type_Id
        And D.Contract_Date=E.Time_Id
        Group By A.Job_Id, A.Location_Id, B.Location_Name, D.Contract_Date
        order by A.Job_Id, A.Location_Id, Year_Contract_Date,Month_Contract_Date 
        ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
Sum (Sum (A.COST_LABOR)+Sum (A.Cost_Material)+Sum ( A.Machine_Hours*C.Rate_Per_Hour))As Total_Cost
```

should be just

```
Sum (A.COST_LABOR) + Sum (A.Cost_Material) + Sum ( A.Machine_Hours * C.Rate_Per_Hour) total_cost
```

---

As of another problem (ORA-00904 for `TOTAL_COST`): you can't reference it within the same `SELECT`; either use current query as an inline view, or use whole calculation (that makes `TOTAL_COST`) to calculate `UNIT_PRICE`, e.g.

```
 Sum (A.Cost_Labor)+Sum (A.Cost_Material)+Sum ( A.Machine_Hours*C.Rate_Per_Hour) As Total_Cost,
--
(Sum (A.Cost_Labor)+Sum (A.Cost_Material)+Sum ( A.Machine_Hours*C.Rate_Per_Hour)) / A.Quantity_Produced as unit_price
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 ^^^^ this is TOTAL_COST
```

Comment: I added some more info about another problem you have; see if it helps.